# PHPSpreadsheet: Keep embedded object when updating template

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I'm using PHPSpreadsheet to read a template file. This template contains some embedded objects and some SmartArt. Then I update some cells and write the changes to a new file. What I want with this file is to keep it exactly like the template, except the changed cells. My problem is that all embedded objects and SmartArt disappears when saving to a new file. Is there any ways to keep everything from the template into the new file, except those exact cells I've changed?

This is a simple example, changing just a single cell. The generated file will loose all embedded graphs and all SmartArt that was in the file.

```
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load("ExcelTemplates/template.xlsx");

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'New headline');

$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save("ExcelOutput/generatedFile.xlsx");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't.... If PHPSpreadsheet doesn't know how to handle an element (such as form components, embedded objects, etc) then it can't be loaded, and therefore isn't available when saving

That probably isn't the answer you want; and the only alternative options that are likely to work are using COM with MS Excel itself (if you're on a Windows server), PUNO with Libre/Open Office, or Ilia's extension wrapper for the commercial libXl library

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but thank you for the help Mark. I'll find a way to avoid embedded objects in my template.

Comment: Found out Apache POI handles this problem perfectly, so I'll use that.